# swift make and access an array from any controller

Tags: arrays, swift

I would like to create an citiesArray class/struct ? and it it contain the array below

```
    let australia = ["Adelaide": CLLocation(latitude: -34.9286600, longitude: 138.5986300),"Albury": CLLocation(latitude: -36.0737, longitude: 146.9135)]
```

then in any controller instead of copy and pasting this array over and over

i would like to simply type something like

let array = citiesArray.australia from any controller in my app

Comment: Just declare it at global level i.e. outside any class.

Answer (score 2):

```
Class CitiesArray {
    static let australia = []
}
```